# Strikethrough UITableView cell text after cell containing String

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, strikethrough

I'd like to strikethrough all cell text in UITableView after a specific line of text.

[Example (after "+")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYpeQ.png)

I think I'm close, but the strikethrough isn't applied in the Simulator. (build is successful)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

   if indexPath.row > dailyTasks.index(of: "+")! {

    let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: dailyTasks[indexPath.row])
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

    cell.textLabel?.attributedText = attributeString

   } else {
     cell.textLabel?.text = dailyTasks[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "GillSans-Light", size: 17)
    cell.indentationLevel = 1
    cell.textLabel?.addCharactersSpacing(1.2)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.99, green:0.97, blue:0.91, alpha:1.0)
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Maybe you just can't see it. The simulator often swallows lines, because it cannot give a pixel accurate representation of the iPhone on your computer screen if for example you scaled the simulator to represent the size of the device accurately. Try to see if it is there once you enlarge the simulator.

Comment: Try setting the label's text after you set the label's other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the font on the label if you are using an attributed string; instead set the font as an attribute.  Here is a playground that shows how to do it:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let label = UILabel()
let text = "sample text"
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] =
    [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "GillSans-Light", size: 17)!,
     NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
     NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle: 1]
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
view.addSubview(label)
label.sizeToFit()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: FYI - you can remove `NSAttributedStringKey` before each of the keys - easier to type. And don't hardcode `1` for the strikethrough type. Use `NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Josh and rmaddy. Changing the attributed string placement and moving the .font command worked.